# SOAP Messages In Eclipse don't trace

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, soap, jax-ws

I novice in jax-ws

I have following interface

```
@WebService(name = "HelloWorld", targetNamespace = "http://pack/")
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.RPC)
public interface HelloWorld {


    /**
     * 
     * @param arg0
     * @return
     *     returns java.lang.String
     */
    @WebMethod
    @WebResult(partName = "return")
    public String getHelloWorldAsString(
        @WebParam(name = "arg0", partName = "arg0")
        String arg0);

}
```

following implementation

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "pack.HelloWorld")
public class HelloWorldImpl implements HelloWorld{

    @Override
    public String getHelloWorldAsString(String name) {
        return "Hello World JAX-WS " + name;
    }

}
```

following client code:

```
public class HelloWorldClient{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:9999/ws/hello?wsdl");

        //1st argument service URI, refer to wsdl document above
    //2nd argument is service name, refer to wsdl document above
        QName qname = new QName("http://pack/", "HelloWorldImplService");

        Service service = Service.create(url, qname);

        HelloWorld hello = service.getPort(HelloWorld.class);

        System.out.println(hello.getHelloWorldAsString("mkyong"));

    }

}
```

In console I see

> Hello World JAX-WS mkyong

TCP/IP monitor:
[image: TCP/IP monitor]

I configure it so:
[image]

Why I don't see messages at TCP/IP monitor?

**UPDATE** Pignic

if I type same local monitoring port  and port(ok button disabled)
I see next:
[image]

**UPDATE 2**

after that

[image]

I see old behaviour

**PUBLISHER**

I forget add code for publisher:

```
public class HelloWorldPublisher{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:9999/ws/hello", new HelloWorldImpl());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that in "Hostname" you should put "localhost" 
and in "LocalPort" You should put "9999".

Comment: Ok, my bad, I have not understood the question.
The TCP/IP Monitor is acting like a proxy so you need to call your service with the "local port"(8080) of your monitor and not 9999
So your url in the client should be "http://localhost:8080/ws/hello?wsdl"

Comment: In your HelloWorldClient, use "http://localhost:8080/ws/hello?wsdl" instead of "http://localhost:9999/ws/hello?wsdl" to use the TCP/IP Monitor. The monitor will record the entry and will call your service (like a proxy)

Comment: strange but it is works. publish to one port and client send request for another port. it is normally?

Comment: yup, in fact, you address your monitor and it forward your request to the server (and register the message in the same time). You should read some informations about proxy.

Comment: Maybe you can suggest something?